# Gain doubloons timing

Tags: mundus-novus

At what moment of their turn do players get doubloons from development cards they own? Do players get doubloons in the same turn they acquire a development card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens at the end of the progression phase. This means you get coins from them in the same turn you get them. See [this thread in BGG](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/717860/clarification-getting-coins-cards-when-exactly).